# How can I combine multiple ggplot2 elements into the return of a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I try to manually compose some elements of a `ggplot2` plot, it works just fine:

```
> p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp), data = mtcars)
> p + geom_vline(xintercept = 20) + geom_point(data = mtcars)
```

But if I try to bundle some of the composition into a function, I get an error:

```
> myFunction <- function() {
+   return(
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 20) + geom_point(data = mtcars)
+   )
+ }
> p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp), data = mtcars)
> p + myFunction()
Error in geom_vline(xintercept = 20) + geom_point(data = mtcars) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Am I missing something in `ggplot2` notation for properly combining `ggplot2` elements within a function body?

Comment: I think the `+` operator requires one of the arguments to be of class `ggplot` in order to properly work its magic.  The geoms are not `ggplot` objects but the plot `p` is.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

ggplot2 supports "list" of the elements:

```
myFunction <- function()
 list(geom_vline(xintercept = 20),
      geom_point(data = mtcars))

p <- ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp), data = mtcars)
p + myFunction()
```

you can keep in a list any piece that ggplot2 function returns, including labs(), opts(), etc, and then use "+" for bind ggplot2 base layer and the piece in the list.

Probably this feature is not widely known , but is very useful when anyone want to re-use a piece of elements.

Comment: Also see Hadley's nice tutorial (mid 2015) on this exact thing: https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970