# Add default label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a default caption to all my charts so that I do not have to type it in for all the charts I make. Is there a way to add default text labels to a theme?

Here's what I'd like to do. I'm using my own theme (`theme_bw` in this example). I would like to avoid typing the caption every time I make a chart. Is there a way to add `+ labs(caption ="Default")` inside `theme_bw()`?

Or can I create a new object with both `+ labs(caption ="Default")` and `+ theme_bw()` that could be called as `+  labs_and_theme`

```
ggplot(diamonds[1:20,], aes(x=carat, y=price)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(caption ="Default") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent tutorial on functional programming with ggplot: https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
library(ggplot2)
labs_and_theme <- list(
  labs(caption ="Default"),
  theme_bw() 
)
ggplot(diamonds[1:20,], aes(x=carat, y=price)) + 
  labs_and_theme + 
  geom_point()
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835332/how-can-i-combine-multiple-ggplot2-elements-into-the-return-of-a-function).