# Globally add caption to all ggplot objects in a script

Tags: r, ggplot2, global

The `ggplot` theme can be globally set using `theme_set()`.

Is there a way to globally add a geom, for example `labs(caption="run ID #")`, to all ggplot objects? I'd like to have a caption automatically applied to all ggplots downstream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. I can't find the SO original answer where I got this from

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_predefined_category_order = c("8", "6", "4")

my_labs  = list(labs(caption = "run ID #"))

my_xaxis = list(xlab("My axis title"),
                scale_x_discrete(limits = my_predefined_category_order),
                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)))

my_theme    <- theme(axis.text  = element_text(size = 20),
                     axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

# Add predefined settings
p + my_labs + my_xaxis + my_theme
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616909/add-default-label-in-ggplot) approach.  I think there are other SO answers out there but I also didn't find them on a quick search. :-)

Comment: Appreciate the convenience, but these geoms are added each time and not set globally as with `theme_set`, so the user has to remember to add it for each plot.

Answer (score 0):

From feedback so far, it seems there is no simple way to do this, so I've edited the `ggplot()` function itself within the `ggplot2` package/namespace.

**I do not like this solution, but it solves the problem for now.** I'd appreciate feedback regarding the drawbacks of this method.

---

We make a plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, col=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now we edit the `ggplot()` function itself and add a default caption to *all* plots that will be output.

```
ggplot.data.frame.original <- ggplot2:::ggplot.data.frame

ggplot.data.frame.custom <- function (data = NULL, mapping = aes(), ..., environment = parent.frame()) 
{
  ggplot.data.frame.original(fortify(data, ...), mapping, environment = environment) +
    labs(caption="My Custom Caption")
}

unlockBinding("ggplot.data.frame", environment(ggplot))
assignInNamespace("ggplot.data.frame", ggplot.data.frame.custom, ns="ggplot2",
                  envir=environment(ggplot)) 
assign("ggplot.data.frame", ggplot.data.frame.custom, envir=environment(ggplot))
lockBinding("ggplot.data.frame", environment(ggplot))
```

We execute the same code to generate the plot as shown above, but this time our default caption appears.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg, col=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]