# Extend ggplot2 Geom to change default "padding" of x and y axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Referencing the [Extending ggplot2](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html) guide, suppose I want to create my own geom in which the default ggplot behavior would be:

- the `x` axis ranging from `min(x)` to `max(x)` exactly
- the `y` axis ranging from `min(y)` to `max(y)` exactly

And no padding! (like in the current default behavior for all geoms)

Let's repeat the example from the guide, `geom_simple_point`:

```
GeomSimplePoint <- ggproto("GeomSimplePoint", Geom,
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),
  default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black"),
  draw_key = draw_key_point,

  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    grid::pointsGrob(
      coords$x, coords$y,
      pch = coords$shape,
      gp = grid::gpar(col = coords$colour)
    )
  }
)

geom_simple_point <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                              inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomSimplePoint, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_simple_point()
```

Where would I change the code to have the panel stretch to the data **exactly** (min to max, x and y, no padding) by default? I.e. only what's in the red dashed line:

[image]

I looked at `draw_key`, doesn't seem to be related. I looked at `draw_panel`, doesn't seem to have parameters which take care of that.

UPDATE:
If I add `print(panel_params)` inside `draw_panel` I can see this is where ggplot gets "the idea" of padding or expanding:

```
$x.range
[1] 1.33 7.27

$x.labels
[1] "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"

$x.major
[1] 0.1127946 0.2811448 0.4494949 0.6178451 0.7861953 0.9545455

$x.minor
 [1] 0.02861953 0.11279461 0.19696970 0.28114478 0.36531987 0.44949495 0.53367003 0.61784512 0.70202020 0.78619529
[11] 0.87037037 0.95454545

$x.major_source
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

$x.minor_source
 [1] 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0 6.5 7.0

$x.arrange
[1] "secondary" "primary"  

$y.range
[1] 10.4 45.6

$y.labels
[1] "20" "30" "40"

$y.major
[1] 0.2727273 0.5568182 0.8409091

$y.minor
[1] 0.1306818 0.2727273 0.4147727 0.5568182 0.6988636 0.8409091 0.9829545

$y.major_source
[1] 20 30 40

$y.minor_source
[1] 15 20 25 30 35 40 45

$y.arrange
[1] "primary"   "secondary"
```

If I manually change `panel_params`'s `x.range` and `y.range` fields it seems to work at first:

```
GeomSimplePoint <- ggproto("GeomSimplePoint", Geom,
                           required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                           default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black"),
                           draw_key = draw_key_point,

                           draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
                             panel_params$x.range <- range(data$x)
                             panel_params$y.range <- range(data$y)
                             coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
                             grid::pointsGrob(
                               coords$x, coords$y,
                               pch = coords$shape,
                               gp = grid::gpar(col = coords$colour)
                             )
                           }
)
```

[image]

But then if you look at the plot closely you'll see that the labels and their locations haven't changed - because I haven't changed them and I need to do this also manually.

If I don't have a choice I'll go manual. But isn't there a way `panel_params` could be obtained not manually with a simple `expand = FALSE` parameter? I looked through the ggplot code and it was very hard to find.

Comment: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes/blob/master/R/scales.r#L120-L138

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr, but how is a function returning a scale (with my precious `expand = FALSE` parameter) helping here? See my update, maybe I'm more focused.

Comment: You aren't satisfied with `geom_simple_point <- function(...) {list(layer(...), coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE))}`, are you?

Comment: I'm very satisfied actually, write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you (and I) were overthinking. `... + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` gives the output you want. And as described in [How can I combine multiple ggplot2 elements into the return of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835332/how-can-i-combine-multiple-ggplot2-elements-into-the-return-of-a-function), you can combine `+ coord_cartesian()` into your function using `list()`.

I think here is what you want;

```
geom_simple_point2 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                               position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                               inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  list(
    layer(
      geom = GeomSimplePoint, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat, 
      position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
    ),
    coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
  )
}
```