# reducing code for symmetric plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often have plots like the following, which are symmetrical, so x and y axis are basically similar except for the data, but I always need to define `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` separately even if they are almost the same. The same accounts for `scale_x_continous`. Is there a more convenient way to define two similar axis or do I always need to define them separately?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(200, sd=3),
                 y=rnorm(200, sd=3))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1, 0, 1), 
             color=c("red", "grey", "red"), linetype=c('dashed', 'solid', 'dashed')) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 0, 1), 
             color=c("red", "grey", "red"), linetype=c('dashed', 'solid', 'dashed')) + 
  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, color='grey20', alpha=.3) +
  scale_x_continuous('my y', 
                     breaks=seq(-100,100,4), minor_breaks=seq(-100,100,1), 
                     limits=c(-13.5, 13.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous('my y', 
                     breaks=seq(-100,100,4), minor_breaks=seq(-100,100,1), 
                     limits=c(-13.5, 13.5))
```

Comment: I think the upcoming ggplot realease one can write: `scale_x_continuous(
                     breaks=seq(-100,100,4), minor_breaks=seq(-100,100,1), 
                     limits=c(-13.5, 13.5), aesthetics = c('x', 'y'))`

Comment: This would be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks, I will keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out based on this question [How can I combine multiple ggplot2 elements into the return of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835332/how-can-i-combine-multiple-ggplot2-elements-into-the-return-of-a-function).

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(200, sd=3),
                 y=rnorm(200, sd=3))

baseDesign <- function(line_colors = c("red", "grey", "red"),
                line_types = c('dashed', 'solid', 'dashed'),
                plot_breaks = seq(-100,100,4),
                plot_minor_breaks = seq(-100,100,1),
                plot_limits = c(-13.5, 13.5)) {
  p <- list(geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1, 0, 1), 
                    color=line_colors, linetype=line_types),
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 0, 1), 
               color=line_colors, linetype=line_types),
    scale_x_continuous(expression(log[2]*" SILAC ratio (female - male)"), 
                       breaks=plot_breaks, minor_breaks=plot_minor_breaks, 
                       limits=plot_limits),
    scale_y_continuous(expression(log[2]*" LFQ (female - male)"), 
                       breaks=plot_breaks, minor_breaks=plot_minor_breaks, 
                       limits=plot_limits))
  return(p)
}
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, color='grey20', alpha=.3) + 
  baseDesign()
```